Mahdi and the Christian Antichrist
Can someone verify these characteristics about the Mahdi , here is a Christian claim
""
In broad terms, what the Bible says about the Antichrist are the same attributes as the 12th Imam, or Mahdi, in Islam’s writings. Here are some of the main similarities (there are more):
Spiritual world leader (Revelation 13:8)
Rides on a white horse (Revelation 6:2)
Seven year covenant/treaty (Daniel 9:27)
Global seat is on the Temple Mount in Jerusalem (Daniel 9:27, 2 Thessalonians 2:4)
Beheads non-believers (Revelation 20:4)
Will the Mahdi reappear, unite the Sunnis and Shias, and establish a Caliphate? Will he be the foretold Antichrist? Time will tell, but the case is rather uncanny and compelling."
Can someone respond to these claims

This question is absurd and a person using even a little bit of common sense should dismiss these arguments. As an example in Revelation 19:11 a rider of a white horse is praised as being righteous: "And I saw heaven opened, and behold a white horse; and he that sat upon him was called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he doth judge and make war." so are you now gonna say that Imam Mahdi is a positive figure in the Bible?

@UmH AFAIK, there's no consensus among Christian scholarship as to whether Rev 6:2 refers to (a) a righteous figure that will precede the Antichrist, (b) the Antichrist himself and/or one of his supporters, or (c) just a prophetic warning of an event that will happen before the end times. As far as I know, the whole "Al Mahdi will ride on a white horse" idea is based entirely on an Israeliyyat reading of exactly this verse rather than any hadith, which makes the whole argument somewhat tautological and even more absurd.

@goldPseudo thank you this clarifies most of my doubts

@goldPseudois there anything we know about the Mahdi taking over the temple (is this proved by valid hadith) because this trait is also given to the antichrist

I will start the following hadith from the prophet:

"Do not believe the people of the Book, nor disbelieve them, but say, 'We believe in Allah and whatever is revealed to us, and whatever is revealed to you.' "
— Bukhari 7362

This Christian claim quotes a large number of Biblical references. Even if we were to accept them as accurate Scripture, God's words are being twisted here to promote an opinion rather than to support the Truth.
That alone should be enough to show that these arguments aren't even worth considering, much less responding to.
However, since many Muslims who are weak in imaan are still open to learning their religion from their enemies, those enemies who speak without knowledge and do not have any but their own best interests in heart, I will continue.
These claims are absurd on the face if only because they are being used to judge somebody who they don't even know. Who they have never met. Nobody can point to Al-Mahdi and say "All these traits apply to him" because nobody can point to Al-Mahdi at all, by dint of him not being present.
This is an absurd claim. It would be laughed out of any court. Yet you are expected to believe it based on predictions of how he might present when he shows up.
Again, that alone should be enough to show that these arguments aren't even worth considering, much less responding to. However, I shall continue.
This Christian claim quotes a large number of Biblical references. Even if we were to accept them as accurate Scripture, they are only traits. None of them are uniquely defining. The Antichrist, Al-Dajjal, isn't defined by having a handful of similar traits with any one person; the Antichrist will have ALL of them.
I'm sure there will be plenty of similarities between the Antichrist and Al-Mahdi. Just like there will be plenty of similarities between the Antichrist and Christ Jesus. He will rise to power explicitly because people believe he is a divine figure. That's kinda his whole deal. Believers need to be wary of him for very good reason, since he will deceive many by appearing to be exactly what they are expecting.
And if anyone does appear and claim to be Al-Mahdi, I would hope that both you and your Christian "friend" will be diligent and continue to judge him harshly so you're not suckered in by a fraud. But you seriously need to be able to make that judgement yourself, not by believing any specious argument your enemies will continue to use in order to deceive you.

It's not just that it appears in their scriptures, but our Hadith , so I tried verifying these claims

I have tried verifying these claims , but i couldn't verify if the Mahdi will ride on a white horse , rule from the temple Mount or behead disbelievers without war . About the 7 year claim , it is disputed as other hadiths mention other numbers such as 5,9, 40 etc. . The Mahdi will be a spiritual leader but unlike their Antichrist who will kill people for not worshipping him.

Google does say Mahdi would ride a white horse but doesn't provide any Hadith to back it up , can you check if this is true?

@Tahir You would be better off posting that as a new question.
